# C# Error: Update Requires a valid updatecommand when passed datarow collection with modified rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I know this error/question has been posted a lot. Iv been researching for a while now and still cannot figure how to properly update my database with changes made in my DataTable.

I have a DataTable filled with information from 2 different tables in my database. Changes are only being made to the columns that come from 1 table though. The second table I need to JOIN for calculations.

So when I try to update my database, changes will only be made to the 1 table. I am still need to ado.net, so im having a hard time applying the correct way to apply these changes based on information from MSDN and StackOverflow.

This is the code I have:

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT INCIDENT_NO, report_dt,MIN(theStart) as The_Start, Resolved_DT, Resolution_TIME, resolution_met,response_met,max_response_time,max_resolution_time,impact FROM TICKET_REPORT JOIN TimeTracker ON Incident_NO=theTask WHERE Resolved_DT != '' GROUP BY INCIDENT_NO,report_dt,Resolved_DT,Resolution_Time, resolution_met,response_met,max_response_time,max_resolution_time,impact", sqlConn))
            {
                var calc = new Calculation(holidays, new OpenHours("09:00;17:00"));
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dtResolution.Columns.Clear();
                dtResolution.Clear();
                da.Fill(dtResolution);

               //-------Making calculation changes to columns from one table in datatable here---------
                try
                {
                    da.Update(dtResolution);
                    Console.WriteLine("Update successful");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Updated failed");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                da.Dispose();
            }
```

I leaned that CommandBuilder will create the update command for me, but MSDN says I can only use CommandBuilder if my SELECT statement only includes 1 table, I have 2 two.

Other StackOverflow answers are saying that if im using a JOIN, im on my own.

How can I properly accomplish this update? Can I do this in C#? Should I pass the data table to a stored procedure in sqlserver instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to just create a merge statement inside of a stored procedure, and just pass the datatable to the stored procedure.

Comment: add solution pls